# NetScaler/IIS: 413 Entity Too Large

Tags: iis-7.5, netscaler

I am facing an issue where I am getting a 413 Request Entity Too Large whenever I post/put JSON to our servers running IIS 7.5 through a Citrix NetScaler.

We have tried to set the aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers to 30000, 40000 and 512000, as so:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="xxx" />
</appSettings>
```

as well as setting the `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="xxx"/>`

But without any resolution.

Setting the aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers in our local test environment, where we don't have a Citrix NetScaler, works just fine .

Is there any settings in the NetScaler that I should know of? or Is there some IIS settings I have to be aware of as well, considering that this works in our local test environments I am leaning towards the later, but I wan't all basis covert.

---

Edit: After further investigation, it surely seems that the NetScaler is the source as we can post to the API from behind the NetScaler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it was actually a combination between the two products.

Internally we use SSL and Client Certificates which means we needed to configure a IIS property called "uploadReadAheadSize"

http://forums.asp.net/t/1702122.aspx?cannot+find+uploadReadAheadSize+in+applicationHost+config+in+IIS7+5

This is done in the host config or though the IIS manager.

```
...
<system.webServer>
 <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="{BYTES}" />
</system.webServer>
...
```

We used 10 MB = 10485760 Bytes for now which shows to be enough. Since this is defaulted to 48KB you may reach this rather fast.